# Make procedural texture generate instead of stretching

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural, texture-coordinates

struggling at a basic and probably dumb issue here. I want to use a generated texture that's supposed to create new texture instead of stretching the existing one. With a uv texture I'd know how to solve the problem, but how do I do it with procedural textures?
When extruding in edit mode it does exactly what I want but then stretches after I go back to object mode.

The setup is just what you can see, only a musgrave texture with generated coordinates.

texture before
[image]

texture how I want it to be
[image]

texture after exiting edit mode
[image]

Comment: Use object coordinates instead of generated.

Comment: ... and scale in Edit mode

Comment: Well obviously that would work, but the texture I'm working on uses a multitude of textures and node groups all using generated coordinates. I tried to do that some time ago already but the result I got did not look like it did with generated coordinates, even after hours of tweaking and comparing. Is there no other way to make generated coordinates behave like object coordinates.

Comment: then try to use the Scale values in the Mapping node to correct that?

Comment: As I said already, I have tried that, and it does not work well for what I am trying to do.